# How do I remove skewness from a distribution?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, normal-distribution, skew

I am working with the most famous [Credit Card Fraud Detection](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud) dataset which includes 28 PCA transformed columns. I'm dealing with the most skewed feature of all which after running the following snippet of code turns out to be `V28`:

```py
abs_skew_values = pca.skew().abs().sort_values(ascending=False)
selected_feature = abs_skew_values.index[0]  # index[0]: most skewed feature
selected_feature  # 'V28'
```

`pca` is the Pandas DataFrame containing the entire dataset with the PCA columns (V1, V2, V3, etc.).

Now, I wanted to test two things:

1. How much does the original distribution resemble a **normal distribution**?
2. How much **skeweness** (left or right) is there in the original distribution?

The first thing I have done is plot the histogram of the feature `V28`:

[image: histogram]

There are a lot of data points far from 0, these are right skewing the distribution with a score of `11.192`. Also, tons of outliers outside of the boxplot fences.

I fixed this by applying a log transformation `sign(x) * log(|x|)` rather than plain `log(x)` because there are negative values in the distribution.

[image: transformed_histogram]

It significantly reduced the skew score to `0.184` and you can see less outliers in the distribution.

Running some normality tests also give an insight into how this is clearly not coming from a normal distribution.

```
Anderson-Darling test
---------------------
15.000: 0.576, data does not look normal (reject H0)
10.000: 0.656, data does not look normal (reject H0)
5.000: 0.787, data does not look normal (reject H0)
2.500: 0.918, data does not look normal (reject H0)
1.000: 1.092, data does not look normal (reject H0)

D'Agostino K^2 test
-------------------
statistic=96189.836, pvalue=0.000
```

It turns out that, after the log transformation, there are only 26 outliers that may (or may not) be outliers in other features, therefore I don't think I can outright remove them from the original dataset.

So, my question is, am I right in assuming that the transformation I applied is enough to correct the skewness that originally came from the given distribution?

Bonus points: Why is the `pvalue` in D'Agostino's test exactly 0, shouldn't it be a small number?